# ORDER option in SEQUENCE

Tags: sequence

The system I am referring to is in AS400.
There is an existing sequence as given below:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ID
AS NUMERIC(20, 0)   
    START WITH 1 
    INCREMENT BY 1 
    MINVALUE 1 
    MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999 
    NO CYCLE CACHE 5 ORDER ;
```

This sequence is used in the trigger (Before `INSERT`) of a table to generate the ID of a transaction. There is performance issue for this Insert process.

I am trying to understand the importance of `ORDER` option here. Is it safe if I `ALTER` this sequence to `NO ORDER`? After the `ALTER`, will there be a scenario of duplicate sequence number being generated i.e. will an ID number be generated again that is already present in the table? Could you please clarify. It would greatly help if you could please explain with an example of what will happen with or without `ORDER` in a sequence.

Comment: You'll need to add the appropriate tag for the programming language this is written in.